# Hosting a Wordpress Blog using Apache as sub-directory

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

I have an existing static web-app on S3 behind CloudFront, let's say at `example.com`

I want to add a WordPress blog, which should be accessed at `example.com/blog`

For the WordPress blog, i've set up an ec2 server with Apache and WordPress.

I've added the ec2 server as origin in CloudFront as describe [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/729697/can-i-use-cloudfront-to-serve-a-wordpress-blog-from-the-same-domain-but-a-diffe).

When i'm running:

```
curl example.com/blog
```

i'm getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/blog/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at http://ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

For that reason, I think my problem is not in CloudFront but in the 
configuration of the Apache server.

My question is: how to configure Apache to work this way?

meaning as sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

When Apache knows it will tell a browser 301 Moved Permanently it uses the `ServerName` which you specified on `<VirtualHost>` level or on global level.

If you don't set a `ServerName` it tries to find out a FQDN by a heuristic (a reverse DNS query for one of IP addresses) and a typical sad result is what you get.

Examples:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerName http://example.com
ServerName https://example.com:8443
```